# beautiful soup parse a tags with inconsistent hrefs

Tags: beautifulsoup

I know that it's possible to extract all the a tags in a html page:

```
  mydivs = soup.findAll("a")
```

But what if I just want the tags that have this format:

```
<a href="/experiments/ENCSR7EADCH/">
<a href="/experiments/ENCSR77RTSA/">
<a href="/experiments/ENCSR75YUDJ/">
<a href="/experiments/ENCSR779CZG/">
```

I tried:

```
mydivs = soup.findAll("a", { "href" : "/experiments/ENCSR*" })
```

but this returns an empty list....

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

[regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)

```
import re
mydivs = soup.findAll("a", href=re.compile(r"/experiments/ENCSR"))
```

[CSS Selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
mydivs = soup.select('a[href^="/experiments/ENCSR"]')
```